# How to join or subquery a table representing tiers

Tags: mysql, sql, join, correlated-subquery

I have a fee table that contains fees in a list of price cutoffs based on item pricing. For example the first fee range is for items that are priced at $0 and up to the next tier have a $1 fee. Items that have a price of $25 up to the next tier have a $2 fee, etc. Here is the fee table:

### Fee

```
Cutoff Fee
------ ---
0      1
25     2
100    3
```

Here is the item table with the prices:

### Item

```
Id     Price
------ ------
1      32
2      18
3      2
4      100
```

The result should look like this:

### Desired Item Fees Result

```
Id    Price   Fee     Total Price with fee
----- ------- ------- -----------
1     32      2       34
2     18      1       19
3     2       1       3
4     100     3       103
```

Creating the result has been challenging. Here is what the cartesian product of the join result looks like between the two tables:

```
Id  Price   Cutoff  Fee
--- ------- ------- ---
1   32      0       1 -- eliminate because price is above the next cut 25
2   18      0       1
3   2       0       1
4   100     0       1 -- eliminate because price is above the next cut 25
1   32      25      2
2   18      25      2 -- eliminate because price is below this cut
3   2       25      2 -- eliminate because price is below this cut
4   100     25      2 -- eliminate because price is above (equal to) the next cut 100
1   32      100     3 -- eliminate because price is below this cut
2   18      100     3 -- eliminate because price is below this cut
3   2       100     3 -- eliminate because price is below this cut
4   100     100     3
```

the first where is simple:

```
where price >= cut
```

this narrows the list down to:

```
Id  Price   Cutoff  Fee
--- ------- ------- ---
1   32      0       1 -- eliminate because price is above the next cut 25
2   18      0       1
3   2       0       1
4   100     0       1 -- eliminate because price is above the next cut 25
1   32      25      2
4   100     25      2 -- eliminate because price is above (equal to) the next cut 100
4   100     100     3
```

Here's the question: how do i filter out records that are in the next pricing tier? This is the sql i have so far.

```
select price, cutoff, fee from item, fee
where price >= cutoff;
```

I have tried a subquery:

```
select price, cutoff, fee, 
    (select min(cutoff), fee from fee where cutoff > price) as nextfee 
from item, fee
where price >= cutoff;
```

but this gives the error:

> Operand should contain 1 Column(s)

Comment: You may want to look at a more structured join query and using the `GROUP BY`with the `HAVING` operator to filter conditionnaly on the aggregate `MIN(cutoff)`. I have found subqueries to make these problems more difficult as well as not good practice for performance. If you can post the ideal output (if different from the narrowed list) from that subquery you tried, that would help me show you this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? No subjoins, better for performance and simpler.

```
SELECT i.id, i.price, MAX(f.fee), i.price + MAX(f.fee) 
FROM item i INNER JOIN fee f
ON i.price > f.cutoff
GROUP BY i.id, i.price
```

Comment: I switched to this answer due to simplicity. only had to make one change to >=.

Comment: @dwaz . . . This assumes that the fees are in increasing order, which is not explained in the OP.

Comment: @GordonLinoff if what you  mean is the case where a bigger cutoff has a lower fee than the previous lower cutoff, then you're right, I'm not taking that case into consideration

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this problem is to use a correlated subquery to get the first fee in the `fee` table where the cutoff is greater than or equal to the price:

```
select id, price, fee, (price + fee) as totalprice
from (select id, price,
             (select fee
              from fee
              where price >= cutoff
              order by cutoff desc
              limit 1
             ) as fee
      from item
     ) i
```

Comment: Not quite right, the fees seem to be up one level, so the $2 item is getting the $2 fee and $32 item is getting the $3 fee

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, now the fees are all $1; so still not quite right.

Comment: that's it...the key was to order the cutoff desc.